# Firefox 57 Web console not showing 'value' property from console.log()

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, javascript-debugger

I'm issuing a console.log(obj_name) command while debugging my Angular app and the new Firefox 57 web console shows the object in the Dev. Tools Web Console window, which I can click on, BUT when clicking, it only displays a short list of properties (it doesn't even show the obj name i used). Other browsers like Chrome/Opera show properties like 'value' and object name, Firefox shows only _value, and there's a lot of other properties it's not showing. It used to show all of these in older versions. What happened? How do I access them in Firefox 57??

[image: Firefox 57]

[image: Opera]

Comment: I can't really repro... And when you right click the root object, "*Store as global variable*" then type `temp0.value` you've got it? If you manage to make an [MCVE], feel free to file a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=__default__&product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Console).

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, storing it in a global variable does give access to value, but the whole point is that I want to see a number of default/non-empty properties by default, without having to query for each one via a global variable. This issue can be reproduced by creating any type of a JS/TS object and trying to console.log it.

Comment: so you mean `console.log({foo: 'bar'})` logs an empty object?

Comment: Well not a JS script object. But any Angular type object with a value in it. foo bar works fine. See screenshots above to see what I actually mean, they show the issue. Firefox used to display a navigation pane when an object was clicked, this is no longer the case.

Comment: Was this solved? I just switched projects where I was on an Angular 6 project and am now on an Angular 12 project but none of the values for variables are accessible via the debugger console without having to hunt for it in and adding it to the Global Variable which is NOT a solution but a long workaround.

Comment: @Kaiido any chance you find the solution or cause of this odd behavior of the console not knowing of variable values?

Comment: @linnx88 any chance you find the solution or cause of this odd behavior of the console not knowing of variable values?